# ARIA-roles not work in IE8?

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-8, wai-aria

After thinking about recreating a page for the public sector with HTML5, I came to the conclusion that a mix of HTML5 and ARIA would be the best choice to add even more accessibility for people with disabilities.

So I am currently experimenting with this combination.
[This Page](http://www.clarissapeterson.com/2012/11/html5-accessibility/) has some good starter tutorials.

To combine the new HTML5 `header` element

```
<header>
...
</header>
```

with ARIA

```
<div role="banner">
...
</div>
```

you can use this

```
<header role="banner">
...
</header>
```

they say. With this the CSS selector should look like this

```
header[role="banner"]{
}
```

But whatever I try it the IE8 and Google Chrome it just won’t do anything. But IE8 should be working fine with this.
Firefox and Opera are working like expected.

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

html5 tags doesn't work in IE<9 you'll have to use a [shiv](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/). I'm not sure why it doesn't work in chrome. Do you actually use `”` to quote your attributes instead of `"`?

Comment: no, the stackoverflow-editor changed it that way just like adding colors - i used "

Comment: but it's sayed that even if the browser doesn't know the tag it will be internal changed to a <div> . That combination  with header AND role was sayed to be THAT solution for browsers which can and can NOT interpret html5.. so i'm wondering why it doesn't work?

Comment: @Todeshuegel I may have been a little off when I said they don't work since as symatic tags they don't do anything in the first place but IE8 and lower does not style html5 tags or any tag it doesn't know. You have to use a [shim](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/)

Comment: @Musa - not sure why you're linking to html5shiv.  Cloning the repo and running `git grep role` turns up zero hits.

Comment: Ah - sorry about that.  Just having to tackle this issue myself which is why I pointed it out.  For future readers, it seems [webshim](https://github.com/aFarkas/webshim) supports this currently.